# insert value to all spreadsheets and reference to a single sheet

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have a spreadsheet"ProductIDList" and many other spreadsheets. With "ProductIDList",column A is product name and column B is productID. I want to insert the productID to column C of other spreadsheets by matching the Product name in "ProductIDList" and other spreadsheets.
I compose this code but it cannot run.
Please help :-(

```
Sub InsertProductID()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer

For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name = "index" Or ws.Name = "ProductIDList" Then GoTo NEXXT
 NEXXT:

  ws.Activate

    For i = 1 To 30000
    For k = 1 To 30000

       If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets("ProductIDList").Cells(k, 1) Then
        ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = Sheets("ProductIDList").Cells(k, 2).Value
       End If

    Next
    Next

Next
End Sub
```

I edited my code. It can run now! But as what you guys said, it runs very very slow.

```
Sub InsertProductID()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer

For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "index" And ws.Name <> "ProductIDList" Then

ws.Activate

For i = 1 To 70
For k = 1 To 70

   If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets("ProductIDList").Cells(k, 1) Then
    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = Sheets("ProductIDList").Cells(k, 2).Value
   End If

Next
Next

End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: *but it cannot run* - please be more specific with your error.

Comment: the code from `NEXXT` will also be executed if your `IF` is `false`... also, you should not iterate through all cells... better use `Application.Index` or `Range.Find` (this will be much faster)...

Answer (score -1):

I think that this code will run really slow.

In particular, I don't understand the meaning of following two lines:

```
If ws.Name = "index" Or ws.Name = "ProductIDList" Then GoTo NEXXT
 NEXXT:
```

If your goal is to **skip** the sheets named "ProductIDList" and "index", you have - at least - to put your *NEXXT* label just before the last `Next` statement. In general, I would avoid to use unconditional jumps, anyway.

What about trying to use some formula functions, like VLOOKUP? In general, they are much faster, but I don't know the requirements of your application.

Comment: More of a comment asking for clarification

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I just don't want to change index and ProductIDList, these 2 sheets also contain the product names

Comment: @dbmitch I did not have the reputation to comment yesterday... anyway, the user changed the code to correctly skip the sheets, and the code worked, as Dirch Reichel suggested in the comments!

Comment: @mobility No problem for the ambiguity, as also other users pointed out, iterating through cells is a really slow operation. You can gain a little bit in execution time either trying to stop calculation programmatically, or hiding the worksheet, or disabling user interface updates, via the Application object (Application.Calculation and Application.ScreenUpdating), but this strongly depends on the rest of your workbook.